# Access Job Parameter in Custom ItemProcessor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, itemprocessor

I am implementing a custom ItemProcessor<I, O> in spring batch for processing data from a Rest api .

I want access some values from jobParameter inside my ItemProcessor class .
Any suggestion on how to do that ?

In Tasklet we can access JobParameter but not sure how to do in ItemProcessor .

MyItemProcessor.java

```
@Component  
public class MyItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<User, UserDetails> {
    

    @Override
    public UserDetails process(User user) throws Exception {
        // access values from job parameter here

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your item processor step-scoped and inject job parameters in it. The following is one way of doing that:

```
@Component
@StepScope  
public class MyItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<User, UserDetails> {
    
    @Value("#{jobParameters}")
    private JobParameters jobParameters;

    @Override
    public UserDetails process(User user) throws Exception {
        // access values from job parameter here

        return null;
    }
}
```

You could also inject a specific parameter if you want with something like the following:

```
@Component
@StepScope  
public class MyItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<User, UserDetails> {
    
    @Value("#{jobParameters['myParameter']}")
    private String myParameter;

    @Override
    public UserDetails process(User user) throws Exception {
        // use myParameter as needed here

        return null;
    }
}
```

Since field injection is not recommended, you can inject job parameters in your item processor when you define it as a bean, something like:

```
// Note how nothing related to Spring is used here, and the processor can be unit tested as a regular Java class
public class MyItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<User, UserDetails> {
    
    private String myParameter;

    public MyItemProcessor(String myParameter) {
        this.myParameter = myParameter;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails process(User user) throws Exception {
        // use this.myParameter as needed here

        return null;
    }
}
```

Once that in place, you can declare your item processor bean as follows:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public MyItemProcessor itemProcessor(@Value("#{jobParameters['myParameter']}") String myParameter) {
    return new MyItemProcessor(myParameter);
}
```

Fore more details about scoped beans, please check the documentation here: [Late Binding of Job and Step attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#late-binding).